# trying to set a member ArrayList using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, containers

I am trying to modify an object with an Arraylist of objects using reflection.

I understand that I cannot get the type of the objects in the ArrayList, but I (think) I am using an annotation to handle that part.  I am setting the field accessibility.

I am declaring the list of stuff in the class using annotations.

```
@TableAnnotation(type = PhoneNumber.class)
protected List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
@TableAnnotation(type = Address.class)
private List<Address> addresses= new ArrayList<>();
private List<Role> roles= new ArrayList<>();
```

... Later in the same class I try to set them:

```
public void setMemberTable(List<Table> tables, String memberName) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class t = getClass();
    for (Field field : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getName() == memberName) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            List array = (List)field.get(this.getClass()); <<<=========== Here is where it is throwing
            ArrayList arrayList= (ArrayList)field.get(this.getClass());
            //array.add(tables.get(0));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Annotation that seems to be working:

```
package com.test.database.helpers;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TableAnnotation {
    Class< ?> type();
    boolean allowNull() default false;
}
```

This throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get java.util.List field com.test.database.entities.Person.phoneNumbers on java.lang.Class
```

I tried making the member variable public, but that had no affect.
I need help to be able to set the member variables in setMemberTable().

Answer (score 2):

> ```java
> (List)field.get(this.getClass());
> ```

The `.get` method on `j.l.reflect.Field` requires the instance that you want to get the field from. You're passing the class. Which is an object of type `java.lang.Class`, which, of course, does not have this field, and therefore, you can't get the value of it. You want `this` instead.

Actually, none of this makes sense, you're right there, just read your own field. I assume this is test code, but if not, none of this makes sense in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You ask the wrong object for the value of the field.

When you write

```
field.get(this.getClass())
```

you try to get the value that the (reflected) field has on some instance. The object that you pass to retrieve the value from is `this.getClass()` which is an instance of `java.lang.Class` - and `java.lang.Class` has no field (for example) "phoneNumbers".

To retrieve a field from your instance you must write

```
field.get(this)
```

But then, the commented out line

```
array.add(tables.get(0));
```

doesn't make any sense. Why do you try to add an element from the `tables` list (which is an instance of `Table`) to a list of (for example) "phoneNumbers", which is a list of `PhoneNumber`?

And your claim that the annotation works: I don't see that annotation used anywhere in your code, so it is hard to say whether it works or not...